# Why are background color property of Button and Material widgets not animated in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

If increase duration of animation for a button or material widget, then change the color of these elements, you will notice that the background color does not change smoothly. At the same time, other widget properties are animated.

Was it done on purpose? If yes, then why?

[image]

[Live example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2429329e2d49edd4178d0ba4d8106478)